# Does FB share button contain trackers?

Tags: cookies, html, tracking, iframe

I am considering putting a Facebook share button (shown below) on my website to encourage people to share content to their FB page.

[image: fb share button]

However, I do not want cross site trackers "bloating" my website or tracking users. This is the code I would need to put in the HTML to add the share button to my website.

`<iframe src="https://www.facebook.com/plugins/share_button.php?href=https%3A%2F%2Fmywebsite.com&layout=button&size=large&width=77&height=28&appId" width="77" height="28" style="border:none;overflow:hidden" scrolling="no" frameborder="0" allowTransparency="true" allow="encrypted-media"></iframe>`

**Does this code contain trackers?**

Comment: It's worth mentioning that you may not need to use such invasive code to have a Facebook share button (or at least you didn't used to). Back in my day, we would create a share button with a simple link. Here are a few references: [Facebook share link without JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9120539), [Share Link Generator](http://www.sharelinkgenerator.com/index.html), [buttons.social](https://www.buttons.social/)

Comment: Thanks @FireQuacker I'll check those out

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes.  For years, Facebook has been using its 'like' and 'share' buttons to collect data on users that visit sites where these buttons are installed. This enables Facebook to collect data on people that don't even use Facebook, when these users visit sites where these buttons are installed.

See https://www.technologyreview.com/2015/09/16/166222/facebooks-like-buttons-will-soon-track-your-web-browsing-to-target-ads/ for more info.